# PFUser Property on subclassed PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfuser

I've subclassed the PFObject with the following Class (dynamic properties, and +load & parseClassName Methods in .m file)

```
@interface DAOpponents : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject* fromUser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject* toUser;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isVisible;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isPersistent;
+ (NSString *)parseClassName;
@end
```

In a Unit Test I try to create a Sample DAOpponents-Object:

```
DAOpponents* follow = [DAOpponents object];
follow.fromUser = user1; // caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "PFObject values may not have class: PFUser"
follow.toUser = user2;
[follow save];
```

If I do the same without a subclassed Version of the opponents there's no Exception

```
PFObject* follow = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"DAOpponents"];
[follow setObject:user1 forKey:@"fromUser"]; // no exception!!!
[follow setObject:user1 forKey:@"toUser"];
```

Why does a subclassed PFObject can not point to a PFUser object?

Any help appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried declaring fromUser and toUser as `PFUser*` not `PFObject*`?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I even tried to override the setter / getter manually (without dynamic generation) and a cast "(PFObject*)user1;" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around this problem by first subclassing PFUser, then using my subclass called `User` in my other PFObject subclasses.

My PFUser subclass, User.h:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@class Person;
@class Parish;

@interface User : PFUser<PFSubclassing>
//+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

// Return the current user
+ (User *)currentUser;

@property (retain) NSNumber *acceptedAgreements;
@property (retain) NSNumber *isAdmin;
@property (retain) Person *person;

@end
```

and my User.m:

```
#import "User.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
#import "Person.h"

@implementation User

@dynamic acceptedAgreements;
@dynamic isAdmin;
@dynamic person;

//+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
//    return @"User";
//}

// Return the current user
+ (User *)currentUser {
    return (User *)[PFUser currentUser];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but: I have to override all static methods of PFUser? Is that a bug or why I've to do this?

Comment: PFUser is a special superclass of PFObject (so sayeth the parse.come employee here: https://www.parse.com/questions/get-pfuser-in-pfquery-using-ios-api), and so you need to treat its instantiation a little differently than if it was a subclass.  I don't think you have to override all the static methods - I haven't needed to do so.

Comment: And why do you override `currentUser`? `[PFUser currentUser]` returns an `instancetype`. Called on User this should return a User Object (and not a PFUser). Or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, that's a convenience method for my particular project - I think you can safely ignore it :)