# how to sync parse with local datastore properly?

Tags: parse-platform, synchronization, local-datastore

I am developing an app that uses [parse](https://parse.com/). Getting the data from parse cloud is not a problem. I would like to sync the data with the user's device as well.

I am now thinking of a way how to do this properly. When I query the parse cloud, I get the data, pin them to local datastore and return them for other use. Then, if user has no internet connection, I will query the local datastore instead, but when user gets online again, I need to sync the data with the parse cloud again.

Is this approach good? Is there a better solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good approach to me. At least that's what I learned a while back from the tutorial here: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore

Comment: Sounds good, I am developing the app for iOS, are you using your own local DB or parse's pinning ?

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct one as you shared a link where It got me on the right path.

Comment: I used Parse's pinning. There's still a problem I haven't solved though. On android, pinInBackground() sometimes never finishes. I don't know if it would be the same on iOS but I think it's worth checking.

Comment: That's the same thing that is happening to me. I am literally just googling the issue. I have found out so far, that it might be because of some properties on my subclassed PFObject classes. I have a PFUser property attached to my gameScore PFObject and maybe this is causing the problem to occur. I'm investigating further ..

This seem to solve this issue .. gonna go for that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318276/pfuser-property-on-subclassed-pfobject

Comment: The link you posted seems to be addressing a different issue though. Anyway, did you manage to get pinInBackground() working correctly all the time?

Comment: One thing that is typically always left unanswered is how to remove posts from the local data store once a user has deleted it. What should you do in that situation?